# How do I send my array to the another function? C++

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

So I have this code:

```
// ConsoleApplication2.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int bankDeposit();
    void game();
    void checkVictorySum(int gameFieldCheck[3][3]);

    int totalDeposit = 0;

    int gameField;

    cout << "Welcome to the slot machine, bet a sum and win money depending on the number of equal rows." << endl;
    totalDeposit = bankDeposit();
    game();
    return 0;
}

int bankDeposit()
{
    int deposit = 0;
    int betAbleMoney = 0;

    bool correctDeposit = false;
    bool endOfFunction = false;
    bool incorrectAnswer = true;

    char wantToDepositMore = 'Y';

    while (!endOfFunction)
    {

        while (wantToDepositMore == 'Y')
        {
            while (!correctDeposit)
            {
                cout << "How much money do you want to deposit? " << endl;
                cin >> deposit;

                if (cin.fail())
                {
                    cin.clear();
                    cin.ignore();
                    cout << "That's an incorrect input" << endl;
                }

                else
                {
                    correctDeposit = true;
                }
            }
            betAbleMoney += deposit;
            cout << "You have deposited a total of " << betAbleMoney << " Euro" << endl;
            incorrectAnswer = true;

            while (incorrectAnswer)
            {
                cout << "Do you want to deposit more money? (Y/N)" << endl;
                cin >> wantToDepositMore;

                if (cin.fail())
                {
                    cin.clear();
                    cin.ignore();
                    cout << "That's an incorrect input" << endl;
                    incorrectAnswer = true;
                }

                else
                {
                    incorrectAnswer = false;
                }

                if (wantToDepositMore != 'N' && wantToDepositMore != 'Y')
                {
                    incorrectAnswer = true;
                    cout << "That's an incorrect input " << endl;
                }

                else
                {
                    if (wantToDepositMore == 'N')
                    {
                        endOfFunction = true;
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        correctDeposit = false;
                        deposit = 0;
                    }
                }               
            }                       
        }       
    }
    return betAbleMoney;
}

void game()
{
    void checkVictorySum(int gameFieldCheck);
    srand(time(0));
    int gameField [3][3];
    char mainGameField [3][3];

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            gameField[i][j] = rand() % 3 + 1;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            if (gameField[i][j] == 1)
            {
                mainGameField [i][j] = 'x';
            }

            if (gameField[i][j] == 2)
            {
                mainGameField [i][j] = 'o';
            }

            if (gameField[i][j] == 3)
            {
                mainGameField [i][j] = '*';
            }
            cout << mainGameField[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    checkVictorySum(gameField[3][3]);
}

void checkVictorySum(int gameField[3][3])
{
    int rows = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            cout << gameField[i][j];
            cout << endl;
        }

    }
}
```

I would like checkVictorySum to be able to use the 2d array from game. The reason why I don't just check everything in the same function is that in our assignment we need to have 3 functions.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
//Björn

Comment: The error messaging you're receiving would be equally appreciated.

Comment: Besides my guess in the answer below, what is the problem you're having? I suggest you read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist), it will help you write better questions.

Comment: I recommend simplifying your scenario. Try to make a very simple function which accepts 2D arrays and call that from an equally simple main program. Having the "game" code in addition to the "passing arrays" problem in the same code could be challenging for a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you get errors about implicitly declared functions, and functions not matching their declarations. The reason being that everything in C++ needs to be declared *before* you use it.

In your case this can be done by either putting the function definitions before they are called, or by making function prototypes (which are declarations of the functions).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has nothing to do with passing around 2 dim array as this works:

```
void func(int arr[3][3])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            arr[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int arr[3][3] = {0};

    func(arr);
}
```

Note that an array decays into a pointer when used as a function argument meaning the dimension values are lost. So you either have to know the size(s) of the array or you pass the dimensions along with the array to the function

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to move your function prototypes out of the body of `main()`.

```
int bankDeposit();
void game();
void checkVictorySum(int gameFieldCheck[3][3]);

int main()
{
    ...
}
```